# How to get the length of the value of an xml tag in a file and then remove the characters on the basis of length from that xml tag?

Tags: xml-parsing

```
<LoanAddressDetails>
    <LoanAddressDetail>
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_TYPE>Mailing</LOAN_ADDRESS_TYPE>     
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_1>2197 RIDGEMONT RD</LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_1>
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_2/>
        <LOAN_CITY>GROSSE POINTE WOO</LOAN_CITY>
        <LOAN_STATE>MI</LOAN_STATE>
        <LOAN_ZIP_CODE>48231337</LOAN_ZIP_CODE>
    </LoanAddressDetail>
</LoanAddressDetails>
```

Comment: through a batch script will be preferable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to edit XML using bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873070/how-to-edit-xml-using-bash-script)

Comment: No it's different. I want to first get the length of the value of an XML Tag from a file. And then if its length is greater than 5, remove the characters after the fifth character. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: For XML processing it is always preferable to use an XML parser and not some kind of text processing, because otherwise it could lead to bugs that are hard to impossible to detect.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Can this code be used in a Visual Cron job through some task please?

Answer (score 0):

To limit the length of the `LOAN_ZIP_CODE` element to 5 characters, you can use `xsltproc`, a tiny Linux command line XSLT-1.0 processor, for this. So use the following stylesheet `test.xslt`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Shorten one specific text node to a maximum length of 5 -->
  <xsl:template match="LOAN_ZIP_CODE/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,5)" />
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and pass the input XML file (here named `file.xml`) to the output XML file (here named `target.xml`) using `xsltproc` with

```
xsltproc -o target.xml test.xslt file.xml
```

**Output is:**

```
<LoanAddressDetails>
    <LoanAddressDetail>
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_TYPE>Mailing</LOAN_ADDRESS_TYPE>     
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_1>2197 RIDGEMONT RD</LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_1>
        <LOAN_ADDRESS_LINE_2/>
        <LOAN_CITY>GROSSE POINTE WOO</LOAN_CITY>
        <LOAN_STATE>MI</LOAN_STATE>
        <LOAN_ZIP_CODE>48231</LOAN_ZIP_CODE>
    </LoanAddressDetail>
</LoanAddressDetails>
```

Of course you can use this command in a bash script.

Comment: Two more things please. I want to edit the length of a single node which is LOAN_ZIP_CODE, not all nodes. Secondly how to write the output of xsltproc into a file?

Comment: @ZaheerChughtai: I updated my answer with the new requirements.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. One more thing, is there a way we can call xslproc in a loop to read the xml files one by one in a folder and then fix them? And on fixing the last file, it exit automatically?

Comment: You can do this with a bash `for` loop: `for f in *.xml; do xsltproc -o "$f"_target.xml test.xslt "$f"; done`.

Comment: That's so kind of you but I need to run this xsltproc through a .bat file or through some windows environment, like Visual Cron. Is it possible to modify it to make it compatible with windows please?

Comment: Also I need to set the directory where from it should pick xml files.

Comment: You do not have to use `xsltproc` as an XSLT processor. Just use whatever XSLT-processor you have available and put it into a batch script. I can't help you with Windows programs.